# Google search engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, google-search

I've got Rails + Backbonejs application. And a lot of pages with useful for search content are showing with backbonejs - so all search info adding with js. As I understand google search use only html responses to grab content and it can't crawl under 'js' pages.

In this case, is it acceptable and valid for google search engine to create html pages, with the same as in 'js' pages content and allowing only for google bot requests. Other requests will be redirecting to appropriate 'js' pages?

For example: google bot find html page 'sitename.com/users/N'. And index it with all content. In search results will be shown link 'sitename.com/users/N'. User click on it, and he redirected to 'sitename.com/#users/N'.

Answer (score 1):

set up your server so that 'sitename.com/users/N' delivers the same content as seen by accessing 'sitename.com/#users/N'. That will then work with any search engine (believe it or not google isn't the only one..) as well as text browsers, screen readers, and browsers with js disabled. You js can then hijack the links and input elements if it's available..

Comment: Thats perfect idea, but in this case it involved in a lot of work - application is  based on js - there are really plenty tons of js. So I'm looking for easiest way to make links and content on pages indexing with google.